# Use mathematica to check whether a matrix can obtained from a given matrix under specific operations

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

For a given matrix A, only the scalar multiplication and row exchange are permitted operation. I wonder how to check whether a matrix B can obtained from A from these operations.

First I tried to check the coefficient of the multiplicaiton, but seems like I have to use a given row of B to divide each row of A, which is inefficient. Furthermore, I have no idea to check(if the scalar understood) the exchange of the rows. Sorry for my naive problems.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose

```
A={{1,2,7},{2,3,4},{5,4,3}};
B={{10,8,6},{4,6,8},{2,4,14}};
DeleteCases[Map[Reduce[#*c==B,c]&,Permutations[A]],False]
```

which returns

```
{c==2}
```

and

```
A={{1,2,7},{2,3,4},{5,4,3}};
B={{10,8,7},{4,6,8},{2,4,14}};
DeleteCases[Map[Reduce[#*c==B,c]&,Permutations[A]],False]
```

which returns

```
{}
```

all of which says the first example does have a solution under row exchange and scalar multiplication while the second example does not.

NONE of this addresses efficiency. If you want to think very carefully about the design of an algorithm that correctly determines whether there is a solution under scalar multiplication and exchange of rows and does this with less than n^2*Factorial[n] operations and you can present a convincing case for the number of operations needed on average for your algorithm then go for it.